# Rhyme that matches the entire last syllable

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

I'm looking at a phenomenon in certain Hebrew poetry whereby the rhyming words have the entire final syllable (CVC) matching, instead of just the end of the final syllable (-VC).

Using English examples, that would mean that "report" rhymes with "support" but not "abort" (because the final syllable in "abort" starts with a "b" sound, not a "p" sound).

Is there a technical English word for this kind of rhyme? Something like "complete rhyme" or "full rhyme" or "syllable rhyme"?

Comment: My bad. I thought you were talking about a feminine rhyme.

Comment: @TusharRaj Support and report are not feminine rhyme, but support and abort are masculine rhyme (as I understand the terms). This is somewhere in between I think.

Comment: Is the identity of the last syllable the only criterion? That is not a type of rhyme that is usually considered a rhyme in English, because English rhymes are _stress-based_. Josh’s ‘syllabic rhyme’ is an exact match to the question as you've asked it, but it includes such pairs as _ramble_ and _terrible_, which few would consider to rhyme. Are you perhaps talking more about ***rimes riches***, which require that the entire stressed syllable and all subsequent syllables be identical? So _alighted_ and _delighted_ rhyme with each other, but not with _elided_ and _blighted_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hebrew words are predominantly accented on the last syllable anyway so this issue isn't common then. What I asked about is what I meant at the time to ask about, though I then tried to find examples of such poetry with rhymes using words stressed on the penultimate syllable and found that not all poems matched both syllables. So while your suggested terms are interesting and certainly related, I stand with my original question. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to ***[syllabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Rhyme) rhymes:***

> - a rhyme in which the last syllable of each word sounds the same but does not necessarily contain stressed vowels. (cleaver, silver, or pitter, patter; the final syllable of the words bottle and fiddle are /l/, a liquid consonant.)

(Wikipedia)

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what is being sought.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен No, it's actually exactly what's being sought—the question is whether what's being sought is the right thing. I have a suspicion it may not be.